# Containable Behaviour in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Since a long time as per my knowledge I was using recursive to control my model relationship. If I make any relation between my models it would surely be autoconnected with paginate. To control that I need to use recursive. By default its value is `1` and to contro; that I have to use it as `-1` or `0`. Yes I read about `Containable` behaviour that how it automatically control fetching result from other Models Though relationships are made.

I went through same as writing

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

In my controller I wrote

```
$this->Album->Behaviors->load('Containable', array('autoFields' => false, 'recursive'=>false));
```

But then also my default paginate called data from other Model as well as fetch queries with other Models.

```
$this->paginate['Album'] = array('conditions' => $condition, 'limit' => '50', 'order' => array('Album.id' => 'DESC'));
$this->set('albums', $this->paginate('Album'));
```

My default pagination code as per my expectation data would be only from `Album Model` and to get from other Model I have to describe it in `Pagination` but when I checked it in Debug Kit it shows this.

[image]

As well as fetch data from all variables.
[image]

What should I do ?? Where I am wrong ??

Comment: Can you re-write your question please. I’m having trouble understanding your problem and what outcome you’re expecting.

Comment: I mean to say If I am writing `public $actsAs = array('Containable'); ` in my Model then associated Models data shouldn't be fetched. If I want data from associated model then I should mention in controller. But by default its fetching associated model data no matter I have written `public $actsAs = array('Containable'); `

Comment: @Martin Bean I am expecting response from you if you got my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t want the data of related models, correct me if I’m wrong. 
For this you need to set contain property to false. This will only bring the data of Album model

```
$this->paginate['Album'] = array('conditions' => $condition,'contain' => false 'limit' => '50', 'order' => array('Album.id' => 'DESC'));
$this->set('albums', $this->paginate('Album'));
```

Contain will be helpful when you want to attach multiple model with your query like

```
$this->paginate['Album'] = array('conditions' => $condition,'contain' => array('model1','model2'), 'limit' => '50', 'order' => array('Album.id' => 'DESC'));
```

I hope this will work for you. Thanks

Comment: `public $actsAs = array('Containable'); ` but when i have used this then associated model data shouldn't be fetched. Because using `'contain' => false` to restrict associated model data can also be achieved through `'recursive' => 0`. Then whats the difference between both.

Comment: both are actually same. $actsAs = array('Containable') means that behaviour containable is attached with this model

Answer (score 0):

Even if your model is set to be containable, you can still set the `recursive` to `false` to prevent the fetching of associated data.

Sample model:

```
<?php
class Article extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array('Category');
}
```

Sample controller:

```
<?php
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->Article->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('articles', $this->paginate('Article'));
    }

    public function view($id) {
        $this->Article->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('article', $this->Article->findById($id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. If same thing can be achived by `recursive` then whats the need of `Containable`. And If `Containable` is mentioned then why by default its fetching associated model data ??

Comment: Well, I suggest you read the CakePHP book entry on the Containable behavior: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html